Issues with Changing Layout from LTR to RTL using I18nManager in Expo
I'm trying to switch my app's layout from Left-To-Right (LTR) to Right-To-Left (RTL) dynamically using I18nManager in my Expo project. However, despite using I18nManager.forceRTL(true), the layout remains LTR even after calling Updates.reloadAsync().
Here is the relevant code snippet from my App.tsx:
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, I18nManager, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';

export default function App() {
  const [isRTL, setIsRTL] = useState(I18nManager.isRTL);
  const switchLayout = async() => {
    const newDirection = !isRTL;
    I18nManager.allowRTL(newDirection);
    I18nManager.forceRTL(newDirection);
    setIsRTL(newDirection);
    await Updates.reloadAsync();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Current Layout: {isRTL ? 'RTL' : 'LTR'}</Text>
      <Button title="Switch Layout" onPress={switchLayout} />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

i have added
"extra": {
      "supportsRTL": true
    },

to app.json
this issue occurred when i upgrade to expo sdk 51
When I added forceRTL to the extra property in app.json, the app layout changed to RTL. However, it does not revert back to LTR as expected when calling forceRTL(false).
Despite all these efforts, I18nManager.isRTL always returns false, indicating that the layout does not change as expected. Does anyone have insights into why this might be happening or how to successfully implement RTL support in an Expo app?
